# error: failed to push some refs to `path`

Tags: git

This is the first time I ran into this problem.
I commit and push the project after I revise the project.
Log as follow:

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" master:master

Enumerating objects: 44, done.
Counting objects: 100% (44/44), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
remote: fatal: failed to write object
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
error: failed to push some refs to 'path'


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (6360 ms @ 2021/10/27 18:50:51)
```

Comment: It seems file permissions are "wrong" on the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `git push` or `git fetch` (the latter includes `git pull`, which means *first, run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command* ), you get *two* Git commands involved.  One runs on your local machine, e.g., your laptop, using your local repository.  The other runs on whatever computer handles the URL for the *remote*—in this case `origin`—and uses the repository indicated *by* that URL.  You can think of this as the Git Brothers (Jonathan and Drew perhaps?) if you like.

Anyway, for `git push`, *your* Git—whichever brother is running on your machine, using your laptop repository—sends commits and other supporting objects to the *other* Git.  Either Git can tell you things.  When *your* Git tells you something, it just says whatever it is:

```
Enumerating objects: 44, done.
```

This came from *your* Git.

When *their* Git needs to tell you something, it sends the message to *your* Git, which then relays it to you:

```
remote: error: insufficient permission ...
```

So this message is coming from *their* Git.  Their Git is complaining that they don't have permission to add the commits and other supporting objects to their own database.

This means something is wrong on the *other side*.  You can't fix it here; you may not be able to fix it at all.  You must log in ot the other machine.

Now, occasionally, the "other machine" is still your own laptop.  In that (rare) case, you *can* fix it: you just have to give *yourself* permissions.  But that's beyond the scope of this answer, which is just to explain why you *can't* fix it when it's *not* your own machine.  (You've obscured the "path" here and I am guessing that you really mean a URL that refers to some other machine.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will ask the owner of our project to turn on the permissions for me.